# GLES 3.0 Shaders using gl_VertexID does not render on iPhone, but in the simulator

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ios-simulator, glsles, opengl-es-3.0

I'm porting a GLES 3.0 Android application to iPhone, and every shader renders except a few shaders which utilize gl_VertexID. They do render in the simulator though.

Does anyone know if gl_VertexID does not work on the iPhone, or if they act differently than on other implementations?

Comment: From [OpenGL ES 3.0.5 Specification - 2.12.9.5 Shader Inputs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf), page 78: *" The value of `gl_VertexID` is defined if and only if all enabled vertex arrays have non-zero buffer
object bindings.
"*

Comment: Hmm, they do, and I read them as well so they are not optimized away by the shader compiler. Hmm might be something in how I handle the vertex buffer.